# $x\cdot 0 \neq 0$ infinitely many zeroes on a finite interval

Tags: real-analysis

I was playing around with polynomials by looking how they behave when I move around their zero points.
I decided to make a function which is zero on a finite interval, but since its a polynomial, it should retain all those nice properties of being differentiable and so on. Using
$$f(x,a,b,N) = \prod_{k=1}^{N} x- \left(a+\frac{b-a}{N}k\right)$$
to put $N$ zeroes between $a$ and $b$ the resulting function, as expected, somewhat resembles $x^N$. 
[image]

Now I want to take the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$, first i turn the product into a sum
$$f(x,a,b,N) = \exp \left(\sum_{k=1}^{N} \ln \left(x- \left(a+\frac{b-a}{N}k\right)\right)\right)$$
and then replace the sum by an integral
$$g(x,a,b) = \exp \left(\int_{0}^{1} \ln (x- (a+(b-a)k)) dk\right)$$
[image]

Suddenly all the zero points are gone and its mostly linear outside of $[a,b]$

with
$$h(x,a,b) = \exp \left(\int_{a}^{b} \ln (x- k) dk\right) = g(x,a,b)^{b-a}\\
= \exp( (x-a)\ln(x-a) -(b-a)-(x-b)\ln(x-b))$$
The graph resembles $f$ more, but is still nonzero everywhere.
[image]

How comes that taking the limit makes such a big difference?

Comment: can exponential function take zero value?

Comment: @GA316 At $-\infty = \ln(0)$ it can, but somehow those values disappear when turn the sum into an integral

Comment: To compare the graphs of $f$ and $g$ is odd since, even if one chooses to be sloppy with the problems of sign, one sees that $g(x,a,b)$ is related to the limit of $f(x,a,b,N)^{1/N}$ when $N\to\infty$, not of $f(x,a,b,N)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your very first step,
\begin{align*}
f(x, a, b, N)
  &= \prod_{k=1}^{N} \left(x - \Bigl(a + \frac{b - a}{N}k\Bigr)\right) \\
  &= \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N} \log\left(x - \Bigl(a + \frac{b - a}{N}k\Bigr)\right)\right),
\end{align*}
is seriously problematic, since the product is not non-negative in $[a, b]$.

Comment: Well, then I get some complex intermediate results, but it doesnt seem like a big problem to me to write $\exp(\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+1))$ instead of $(x-1)(x+1)$